# adding classes through generic mouse over event

Tags: jquery

I have four background images on main page each parent of the background image has the width of 25% so that they can take up to full screen,now i have to do something like when  one of them is hovered i need to add the class **width-37**  which means i am increasing the width of that specific div, by increasing the width of that specific i then need to decrease the width of other divs so that they may remain on the same line for that i will be adding the class **width-27** to the divs other than the current div which has the **width-37**
here's my current code

Html:-

```
<div class="index-rel" id="index-height">
  <div class="width-25">
    <div class="img img1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-25">
    <div class="img img2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-25">
    <div class="img img3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-25">
    <div class="img img4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="index-abs">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.index-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.index-rel .width-25 {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.index-rel .width-37 {
  width: 37%;
}

.index-rel .width-21 {
  width: 21%;
}

.index-rel .img {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 53% center;

  }

.index-rel .img1 {
  background-image: url("../images/index (3).jpg");
}

.index-rel .img2 {
  background-image: url("../images/index (4).jpg");
}

.index-rel .img3 {
  background-image: url("../images/index (1).jpg");
}

.index-rel .img4 {
  background-image: url("../images/index (2).jpg");
}
```

jQuery:-

```
$("#index-height").height($(window).height());

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".index-rel .width-25").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("width-37");
  });
  $(".index-rel .width-25").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("width-37");
    $(this).removeClass("width-21");
  });
});
```

now the problem is i couldnt really make the logic in Jquery that **on mouse over** add **width-37** to the current div and add **width-21** to the other divs! any help?

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wojihibeqi/edit?output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do like below:-

```
$("#index-height").height($(window).height());

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".width-25").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("width-37");
        $('.index-rel').children().not($(this)).addClass('width-21');
    });
    $(".width-25").mouseout(function(){
        $('.index-rel').children().removeClass('width-21');
        $('.index-rel').children().removeClass('width-37');
    });
});
```

Working example:- https://jsfiddle.net/5gcLq089/

Comment: sorry my bad! just messed up the css a bit

Comment: @uneebmeer  glad to help you :):)